# Can Symbols be used to create truly private fields on an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, symbols

Using JavaScript, can Symbols be used to create truly private fields on an object?

How do we do it?

This doesn't work, because it's just going to create a string-based key:

```
let sym = Symbol('foo');
let obj = {};
obj[sym.toString()] = 5;
console.log(obj[sym.toString()]); // 5
```

so how do we assign and retrieve "private" properties on an object, given that we know the Symbol key?

Comment: obj[sym] = 5; would store value at symbol key. which is not iterable. Can be accessed through sym reference.

Comment: Why are you using `.toString()` if you wanted to use the symbol as the property key?!

Comment: I hope the duplicate explains sufficiently why the answer to your title question is *No*.

Comment: So not *truly* private fields?

Comment: The other question is painfully general